# Design for surface in pygame

Tags: image, pygame, crop

I am making a game and I am using walls there. I want to make a design for them but I don't know how to do that. I am thinking about making an image and each wall crop from it, depends on its size. How can I do that? I just filled here with a color.

```py
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill((50,50,225)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
```

These are the walls that I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: just use paint or some other similar app and draw it there

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended, you could use tilemaps or tiled (pygame module) as they are easier.